# Display a table with just the second duplicate rows removed yet keep the first row

Tags: ms-access, vba, duplicate-data

So, I have a table with 3 columns, of which the first column consists of IDs and the last column consists of dates. What I need is, to sort the table by dates, and remove any duplicate IDs with a later date (and keep the ID with the earliest date).
For example,
This is how my table originally looks like -

- 123  Ryan  01/01/2011
- 345  Carl  03/01/2011
- 123  Lisa  01/02/2012
- 870  Tiya  06/03/2012
- 345  Carl  07/01/2012

I want my resultant table to look like this -

- 123  Ryan  01/01/2011
- 345  Carl  03/01/2011
- 870  Tiya  06/03/2012

I'm using VBA Access Code to find a solution for the above, and used SQL Queries too, however my resultant table either has no duplicates whatsoever or displays all the records.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is adding a unique ID to your table an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Although I could create a new table which will display the results of this table without the unique ID (if that helps). I just want to display the first row of each of the duplicate records including the remaining unduplicated records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a new table:

```
SELECT tbl.SName, a.ID, a.BDate
INTO NoDups
FROM tbl 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  ID, Min(ADate) As BDate 
    FROM tbl GROUP BY ID)  AS a 
ON (tbl.ADate = a.BDate) AND (tbl.ID = a.ID);
```